# Will this UPDATE accomplish what I intend it to?

Tags: sql-server

This is probably a very simple question for you SQL folks out there.

I have a temp table (TMP_VALIDATION_DATA) in which I've stored the old and new values of some fields I wish to update in a production table (PROVIDER_SERVICE), plus the uuids of the PROVIDER_SERVICE records that need to be updated.

What I want to accomplish is this, in pseudo-code:

```
For every prov_svc_uuid uuid in TMP_VALIDATION_DATA table
  Set PROVIDER_SERVICE_RATE.END_DATE = NewPvSvcEndDate
  Where [uuid in temp table] = [uuid in PROVIDER_SERVICE table] 
end for
```

Is this Update statement going to accomplish what I need?

```
update PROVIDER_SERVICE
set END_DATE = (
  select NewPvSvcEndDate 
  from TMP_VALIDATION_DATA T
  where T.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID = PROVIDER_SERVICE.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID 
)
```

If my UPDATE is incorrect, will you please provide the correction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will update all records and you might get an error if you have more than one record in your subquery.  I would also change your syntax to a `JOIN` similar to below.

```
update P
set END_DATE = T.NewPvSvcEndDate
FROM PROVIDER_SERVICE P
JOIN TMP_VALIDATION_DATA T
   ON P.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID = T.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID
```

If you don't want to `UPDATE` all records, then add a `WHERE` clause.

My suggestion is if you don't know how many records would be included in the `UPDATE`, write your query as a `SELECT` first, then change it to an `UPDATE`. So for this one:

```
SELECT P.END_DATE, T.NewPvSvcEndDate
FROM PROVIDER_SERVICE P
JOIN TMP_VALIDATION_DATA T
   ON P.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID = T.PROVIDER_SERVICE_UUID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will either update all records, or error out (not sure what happens when you try to update a column with multiple values like that).